# How do I count how many files deleted from GIT repo?

Tags: git

I am new to GIT. In BK, when user "bk rm" files, they are sitting in the deleted area. I can count how many files have been deleted by users. How do I count the user-deleted files in GIT? I did "git status":

=>> git status

## On branch master

nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Thanks.

Albert

Answer (score 3):

```
 git-ls-files --deleted
```

should do the trick. If you just want a count, you can

```
| grep -c
```